# Unable to push local repository to GitHub

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Unable to push local repository to GitHub

Steps followed:

1. `mkdir github-local`
2. `cd github-local`
3. `git init`
4. `touch README.md`
5. `git add .`
6. `git commit -m "test commit"`
7. `git remote add origin git@github.com:sounak-patra/github-local.git`
8. `git remote -v`
9. `git push --set-upstream origin master`

Output:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: And did you *"check you have the correct access rights and the repository exists"*? I can't see it [on GitHub](https://github.com/sounak-patra/github-local), is it private?

Comment: no it's public repository

Comment: It *wasn't*, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the remote repository first in order to push into that repository. Before trying to add remote repository (step #7) you must create the remote repo.

The error is self explanatory:

> ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.